# Does this binary operation have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Does the following binary operator on abstract linear maps $A,B:\mathbb{C}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^N$, have a name:

$[\{A,B\}]:= AB^{\dagger} - BA^{\dagger}$

clearly, it is real bi-linear, but not complex bi-linear. It is also anti-symmetric.

Comment: What is the  $^\dagger$ operation?

Comment: The conjugate of a linear map wrt to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^N$.

Comment: To state the obvious: it's the skew-Hermitian part of $AB^\dagger$.